# Generate list of list for start and end date of week from date range

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to generate week list by entering the start date and end date.
Let's say if the start date is **2019-05-01** and end date is **2019-05-31**
then I would like to generate a list of a list like this

```
[['2019-04-29','2019-05-05'],['2019-05-06','2019-05-12'],['2019-05-13','2019-05-19'],['2019-05-20','2019-05-26'],['2019-05-27','2019-06-02']]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are those dates with `04` in them like `2019-04-13` typos or am I missing something? It also looks like your start date is before your start date. How does that work?

Comment: That is a requirement because I need to take exactly one week. I need start date of the week even it is before start date.

Comment: I believe the output you are expecting should be slightly different. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `calendar` builtin module ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar)) for getting the weeks:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_all_weeks(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    one_day, one_week = timedelta(days=1), timedelta(days=7)
    current_week_start = calendar.Calendar().monthdatescalendar(start_date.year, start_date.month)[0][0]
    while True:
        if current_week_start + one_week <= start_date:
            current_week_start += one_week
            continue
        if current_week_start > end_date:
            break
        yield [current_week_start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), (current_week_start + one_week - one_day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
        current_week_start += one_week

d_start = '2019-05-01'
d_end = '2019-05-31'

weeks = [*get_all_weeks(d_start, d_end)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(weeks)
```

Prints:

```
[['2019-04-29', '2019-05-05'],
 ['2019-05-06', '2019-05-12'],
 ['2019-05-13', '2019-05-19'],
 ['2019-05-20', '2019-05-26'],
 ['2019-05-27', '2019-06-02']]
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me.